# How to add data in time format HH:MM:SS on a bar chart in python?

Tags: python, time, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar chart with data in time format in y axis. I would like to generate the same exact bar chart in python, but instead of integers on y axis, i would like to be able to add time format data (in form HH:MM:SS), e.g. 1:32:12 , 2:35:10 etc... Is this possible?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data to plot
n_groups = 4
means_frank = (90, 55, 40, 65)
means_guido = (85, 62, 54, 20)

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.8

rects1 = plt.bar(index, means_frank, bar_width,
alpha=opacity,
color='b',
label='Frank')

rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, means_guido, bar_width,
alpha=opacity,
color='g',
label='Guido')

plt.xlabel('Person')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by person')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width, ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

After finding each timestamp with`datetime.strptime`, You could replace the tick values with corresponding string values (in your case a timestamp) using `plt.yticks(y_values, new_ticks)`, as you did for `xticks`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data to plot
n_groups = 4
means_frank = (90, 55, 40, 65)
means_guido = (85, 62, 54, 20)

# generate timestamps in a loop here!
new_ticks = ('10:01:19', '10:01:25', '10:03:25', '10:04:30')

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.8

rects1 = plt.bar(index, means_frank, bar_width,
alpha=opacity,
color='b',
label='Frank')

rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, means_guido, bar_width,
alpha=opacity,
color='g',
label='Guido')

plt.xlabel('Person')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by person')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width, ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
# here!
plt.yticks(means_guido, new_ticks)


plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[Generated output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEzPu.png)

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to convert your time data with `datetime.strptime` in order to manipulate it in the HH:MM:SS form.

Then you need to convert it in a matplotlib format, thanks to `date2num` in order to plot it.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates

#an exemple of datetime, replace it by your own data
y = [datetime.datetime.now()] 

time = matplotlib.dates.date2num(y)
plt.plot_date(your_x_axis, time)
```